# Why does division require fractionals, but multiplication does not?

Tags: haskell

In ghci:

```
:t (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
:t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

Why does division require fractional inputs?
I mean, I understand 'why' (because it was written to do so), but I don't understand why it was implemented this way? `*` can take and return fractionals, why can't `/` ? I know that `div` and `quot` exist, but I don't see why `/` wouldn't convert it's arguments like `*` seems to (or why it wouldn't just become an alias for div/quot depending on the given arguments.

I'm sure there is a reason, I just can't figure out what it is?

Comment: Multiplication of integers results in integers, unlike division of integers, which can result in non-integers.

Comment: "I don't see why `/` wouldn't convert it's arguments like `*` seems to" -- neither `*` nor `/` convert their arguments at all, so if it seems that way to you you should explain what makes it seem that way. Then we can set you straight. I think this may be the core of your confusion.

Comment: ...and as for "why it [`/`] wouldn't just become an alias for `div`", well, there's just two different behaviors there and both are useful, so why conflate them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might be confused about what the constraints mean.  There is no automatic conversion going on in either of these operations.  The constraint is essentially a set of types which support this operation.  `Num` is the most basic numeric class, and its members include `Integer`, `Double`, `Rational`, etc., which means that `(*)` can have any of the following types:

```
(*) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(*) :: Double -> Double -> Double
(*) :: Rational -> Rational -> Rational
```

Notice especially that all three types are the same -- you have to put in two of the same type, and you always get back what you put in.

You cannot divide two integers and get back an integer in general, so we must not allow

```
(/) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

and that is why there is the more specific class `Fractional` for numeric types which are closed under division.

It would be possible to make `(/)` an alias for `div` in the integer case, as you suggest.  In fact, it *is* possible––you could just write this in your source file:

```
instance Fractional Integer where
    (/) = div
    fromRational = floor
```

Now `Integers` support the `(/)` operator for integer division, just like every other language!  I recommend strongly against this, I think the Haskell language designers got this one right.  Putting aside the total insanity of allowing you to write the literal `0.5` in an integer context and have it silently interpreted as zero instead of an error (which a worrying number of languages allow!), integer division is a very different operation than division.  Division is the inverse of multiplication, and it has these nice laws (IEEE rounding errors notwithstanding):

```
 (a / b) * b = a
 (a + b) / c = (a / c) + (b / c)
```

Integer division is not and does not.  So if `(/)` supported integers, then if you had some polymorphic arithmetic function:

```
someFormula x y = x / (x^2 + y^2) + y / (x^2 + y^2)
```

and you're like, hey, that is unnecessarily complicated, let me simplify it!

```
someFormula x y = (x + y) / (x^2 + y^2)
```

You have just introduced a bug for that user who decided to use `someFormula` on integers, for which it was never intended, because in that case division was not "real" division (no pun intended), and your algebra was wrong.  So that's why we have `Fractional` to indicate that this is an honest type supporting division, that is to say, the inverse of multiplication.

Answer (score 5):

`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` means you can pick any type `a` you like that is a member of `Num`, and `*` can be a function that takes two arguments of that type and returns a result of the same type.

The way type classes work, for each type that is a member of `Num` a separate implementation of `*` must be supplied. So there is one function that is `(*) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`, another that is `Double -> Double -> Double`, another that is `Ratio Word32 -> Ratio Word32 -> Ratio Word32`, etc, etc. `*` can be instantiated as any of those separate functions.

Similarly, `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` means you can pick any type `a`, but here it has to be a member of the `Fractional` type class, which is more restrictive. `Double` is a member of `Fractional`, so there is a `(/) :: Double -> Double -> Double` function. `Integer` is just not a member of `Fractional`, so there is no `(/) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer` function.

The reason `Integer` is not a member of `Fractional` is that mathematical division of integers simply doesn't result in an integer. You need a type that supports fractional numbers between the integers in order for division to make much sense. There are **different** operations like `div` and `quot` that you can perform on integers, and so they work on types like `Integer` and `Int`. If you want one of those operations, you should ask for it, not ask for `/` and expect it to give you a different operation when you use it on integers. Not least because how would it know whether `div` or `quot` is what you think of as "the closest thing to division I can do with integers"? And if you have an `Int`, `Integer`, or similar, and you want to translate it to a fractional number so you can do division with it and get a fractional result, then you'll need to use a translation function like `fromIntegral`; Haskell will not magically insert this for you, but it has all the translation functions and they work just fine.

---

Note that there is no conversion going on when you call `*`; it is not that `*` is happy to convert argument in ways that `/` is not. The `Int` version of `*` **requires** that you provide it with two `Int` arguments, the `Double` version **requires** that you provide it with two `Double` arguments, etc. If you call the `Double` version of `*` but pass it an `Int`, it will not convert the `Int` to a `Double`: you will get a type error.

New Haskellers often think there must be conversion because they can evaluate expressions like `3.2 * 7`, and how else could that work?

In several other popular languages what happens here is that the language implementation says that `3.2` is a floating point number and `7` is an integer, and - like in Haskell - multiplication can only be evaluated with two arguments of the same type. So the language implementation silently inserts some code to translate the integer to the floating point type; what you get is actually something like `3.2 * (floatFromInt 7)`. But just because that is how other languages handle simple arithmetic expressions doesn't make it the only way, and you would do very well to find out how Haskell (or any other language you start learning) *actually* handles these expressions when you start learning the language rather than assuming it must be like it is any other language.

In Haskell, the compiler doesn't start by assuming numeric literals like `3.2` or `7` are any particular type. Haskell is more flexible. Instead any integer-like number in the source code can be read as a literal for *any* numeric type (any type in `Num`), while a decimal-point number in the source code can be read as a literal for any type in `Fractional`. Haskell figures out what what version of `*` is being called by looking at both the context it is used in (the code that consumes the result) as well as the arguments. If *any one* of those things forces a single type, then both arguments as well as the result must be able to be that single type.

So in cases like `3.2 * 7` it is likely that how the result is used will determine what type the result must be, which in turn determines what the type of `*` is in that expression, which in turn determines how each of the numeric literals are read. **Both** will be read in as literals for that same type<sup>1</sup>. In this case we can even determine that `7` is definitely **not** `Int`, or `Integer`, or anything similar, since those types do not have `Fractional` instances and the type used must be a `Fractional` one in order for one of the arguments to use a `3.2` literal containing a decimal point.

---

<sup>1</sup>. Of course what "being read in as a literal for any numeric type" actually means is that an integer literal makes Haskell create an `Integer` and then the `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` function from the appropriate type's `Num` instance can build the "real" value from the `Integer`. Similarly the decimal-point literals are initially read as a value of type `Rational` and then the `fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a` function is used to build the real value.

So if you're being very picky and/or technical, you can argue that `3.2` is in fact always a literal for the fixed type `Rational` and then the conversion function `fromRational` is *always* applied. That is not incorrect, but I view it as an implementation strategy for the concept "`3.2` is a literal for any `Fractional` type". The application of the function will almost always be inlined away at compile time anyway, so at runtime there will only be the values of the final desired type.

I think this point of view is more helpful for new Haskellers precisely because so many get confused expecting automatic type conversion between integers and floating point types to happen as they do in other languages, and that most definitely is not the case; in those other languages that would happen with *variables* of integral types as well. This form of conversion that Haskell has is *only* to do with literals, and it's rather different because the `fromRational` (or `fromInteger`) translator is *always* called when you use a literal, it has nothing to do with promoting a real runtime value of one type to match the type of another operand.

Answer (score 1):

In these types:

```
:t (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
:t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

There are two parts:

1. Constraints :Num, Fractional
2. Types: a

The `a` part means 'any type' you want (subject to the constraints), but it's the same type in every place because it has `a` in every place. Also, please note that no conversion is taking place, precisely because the type is `a` in every place. The `Num` and `Fractional` part is the  'superclass' in the type hierarchy:

[image]

So, `Num a` means Real, or Complex, or Integral, or Int, or Integer, or Fractional , or Float, or Double, or Rational.

The thing is that mathematically integral division is different from fractional division. Thus, Haskell has div for integral division, and / for fractional division.

```
:t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
:t (/) 
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

One of the consequences is that you have to think very carefully about your algorithm. Take for example, calculating the average of the values in a list:

```
average xs = (sum xs) / length (xs)
```

Simple, but wrong. This will not compile, because the types are wrong:

```
:t sum
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
:t length
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
```

So, you have to use Data.List's genericLength.

```
:t genericLength
genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i

average :: Fractional a => [a] -> a 
average xs = (sum xs) / genericLength (xs)
```

Comment: `Complex` numbers are usually also `Fractional`.

Comment: I think it's super misleading to have e.g. `Int` appear "alongside" `Num`, as if they were the same kind of entity.  This isn't OO --types and classes play very different roles in the language

Comment: Also `genericLength` is bad and slow.  `fromIntegral . length` is better for this case.  Pretty much the only "reasonable" (if you can call it that) use of `genericLength` I've seen is using to return a lazy `Nat` type, where it can lazily compute a length, to e.g. compare it with a number without having to evaluate the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, the type classes roughly represent various algebraic structures.

1. `Num` can represent the concept of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), a set of values where additional and multiplication behave "normally" but without requiring division.
2. `Fractional` can represent the concept of a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), which is a (commutative) ring with the added notion of divisibility.
3. `Integral` can represent the concept of a [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), which is a (commutative) ring with a relaxed definition of division called Euclidean division.

Since constrained functions can be thought of as families of functions, you can "specialize" `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` to represent smaller families or specific functions, like

1. `(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int`
2. `(*) :: Float -> Float -> Float`
3. `(*) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`.

Each of the three is a distinct function, the first and second because `Int` and `Float` are instances of `Num`, the third because `Num` is a superclass of `Fractional`.

You can think of third as being the subset of `(*)` functions that have an inverse in the `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` family. The other functions don't have an inverse, but could have related functions in `div, mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` so that

```
a * b == (a `div` b) * b + (a `mod` b)
```

---

(The `Float` and `Double` types break the analogy quite a bit, since operations on them are neither closed nor associative.)